# How to allow single file access instead of directory access using lshell

Tags: linux

I want to read a log file located at a very specific path. I am new to Lshell and have been experimenting with various configurations but have not found a parameter that allows restricted access to a single file. The documentation does not specify such a feature either. The only way I can have access to this file is to either:

1. Enable to whole directory the file is contained under "path:"
2. Create an executable script and give it "allowed_cmd_path:" access

Has anyone been able to successfully implement this feature?